# Mysql group-concat is giving wrong output

Tags: mysql, database

My purchaseproduct table

```
+------------+------------+
| productids | quantities |
+------------+------------+
| 1,3,4,5    | 1,1,1,1    |
| 2,3,4,5    | 1,1,1,1    |
+------------+------------+
```

My product table

```
 productsid | productsname                 |
+------------+-----------------------------+
|          1 | Phone                       |
|          2 | Laptop                      |
|          3 | Charger                     |
|          4 | Earphone                    |
|          5 | Camera                      |
```

I want to get product name based on productids in purchaseproduct table

Like below Out put is needed

```
Phone,Charger,Earphone,Camera (In row one)
Laptop,Charger,Earphone,Camera (In row two)
```

I tried this below statement and many other

```
select group_concat(p.productsname) from purchaseproducts as pp join products as p on find_in_set(p.productsid,pp.productids);
```

But the output I get is

```
 Phone,Charger,Earphone,Camera,Laptop,Charger,Earphone,Camera (All in one row)
```

How can I achieve the output I need?

Comment: You know why you are asking this question? Because you overlooked the database design. Storing comma separated values is just too bad! [**Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) **YES**

Comment: @1000111-Requirement is such that.. :(

Comment: Change the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `DISTINCT` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
select pp.productsid , group_concat(DISTINCT p.productsname)
from purchaseproducts pp 
join products p 
 on find_in_set(p.productsid,pp.productids);
GROUP BY pp.productsid
```

Comment: using distinct is not working it also prints only one row but disting out put

Comment: Need to use `GROUP BY`. By the way, isn't there any `PK` in `purchaseproduct` table? @RajaDhasan

Comment: Thanks working.. I used  group by with a unique PK in my table

Comment: If there were another row having `productsid = 1,4,3,5 ` then you would get three rows. Although you would expect to get `2` rows. That's why `CSV is bad` @RajaDhasan

Comment: @1000111 How do you know he expects to get 2 in this case? And yea, in general I highly agree.. change the DB design!

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Although these two strings (`1,4,3,5`, `1,3,4,5`) consist of the same `product ids` but `GROUP BY` will treat this as different. Correct me if I am wrong. @sagi

Comment: I never said you are wrong, but if he stores both of them, then I'd expect that he'd expect them as well.

Comment: I have a Primary key to sort it out .. I used group by with it to overcome :)